# matplotlib doesn't show plot in docker

Tags: matplotlib

I was running into this error:

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
```

However, even if I added:

```
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

in my script, plt.show() would still not work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, in one of my imported files, I was calling:

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Once a GUI backend is loaded, apparently it cannot be changed without issues.

After commenting out:

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

In my import, everything works as intended.